# Css generated in element.stylet is affecting my webpage and I cannot override

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="imageSlider" style="display: block; z-index: 0; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: -779px;">
```

The left: -779px; is making my image slider not show the first image in the slider. This code is not in my javascript, html or css it's being generated from somewhere though and I am not sure how to stop or override it.

See my page [here](http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/maptest12.html)

Comment: It's possible to set the value for left that you need and end it with !important, like e.g. #imageSlider {left: 100px !important;} The value with this attribute has a higher priority. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override that

```
#imageSlider {
left: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I had tried that but had the syntax wrong! Was trying to do it in the html. Thank you very much for the quick response!